# Пытаюсь создать сервлет в Netbeans, но он выдает ошибки начиная с @Katrin и до * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs

Tags: java, servlet, netbeans

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@author Katrin

@WebServlet(name = "myservlet", urlPatterns = {"/myservlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet MyServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet MyServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Зачем такой сервлет писать?

Comment: Нужно указать текст ошибки прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

`@author` - это дескриптор [javadoc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc), он должен находится внутри комментария

```
/**
* @author  Katrin
*/
@WebServlet(name = "myservlet", urlPatterns = {"/myservlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, но что делать с public class MyServlet...
Если эту часть закоментить, то появляется ошибка " Не удалось развернуть приложение на контекстом пути"

Comment: Искать в логах сервера причину, по которой не удалось.